# In the vertex coloring problem does the minimum sum of all the vertices corresponds to an optimal coloring?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

If vertices of a graph are labelled with positive integers instead of colors in the vertex  coloring problem does the minimum sum of the all the positive integers (such that no two vertices sharing the same edge have the same integer) correspond to an optimal coloring i.e uses the least number of colors(integers). I think that it is false but I can't come up with a counterexample.

Comment: This is bad, for each node, you need to minimize the unique numbers used, subjected each link share two different numbers at each node. You could have 100 links at a single node, and the sum of them do not mean it is optimal or not

Comment: I don't understand what link and node mean?. Like I said in the question I know that the set of integers may not be an optimal coloring but I can't find a suitable counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample.

[image: Example]

If vertices 0 and 4 get colors 2 and 3 correspondingly and all other vertices get color 1 we have sum 11. If we color vertices into two colors (vertices 1, 2, 3, 4 get color 1 and vertices 0, 5, 6, 7 get color 2 or vice versa) we get sum 12.